# Many-particle operators in the occupation number representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I've read that if we have a many-particle operator in the coordinate representation which is the sum of identical one-particle operators operating, however, on different particles, like

$\hat{Q} = \sum_i^{N_P}{\hat{q}(\vec{r}_i)}$

where $N_P$ is the number of particles indexed by $i$, then in the occupation number representation it becomes

$\hat{Q} = \sum_{\lambda'\lambda}\left<\lambda'|\hat{q}|\lambda \right>a_{\lambda'}^{\dagger}a_{\lambda}$.

Similarly, if we have a many-particle operator which is the sum of identical two-particle operators like

$\hat{D} = \sum_{i, j}{\hat{d}(\vec{r}_i, \vec{r}_j)}$

then in the occupation number representation this becomes

$\sum_{\lambda\lambda'\mu\mu'} \left<\lambda'\mu'|\hat{d}|\lambda\mu\right>a_{\lambda'}^{\dagger}a_{\mu'}^{\dagger}a_{\mu}a_{\lambda}$,

however I haven't been able to understand any of the explanations accompanying these statements. Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you mind being more precise? What exact don't you understand. ("any of the explanations accompanying these statements" is not very concrete).

Comment: @user2582713 The first chapter of Fetter&Walecka, "Quantum Theory Of Many-Particle Systems", see http://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/448/Fetter%20Walecka.pdf, has a very detailed explanation of what you are asking about. Can you follow that? If not, can you point out where specifically are you  having difficulties?

Comment: @urdv Thank you very much for that link. I followed the first few pages through and it makes sense to me now.

Comment: @udrv I realise I'm probably abusing the Stack Exchange system here, but do you mind taking a look at a related [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232680/fetter-waleckas-derivation-of-second-quantised-canonical-schrodinger-equation) I posted yesterday?

Comment: No problem, saw your message too late today, but I'll take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Much appreciated.