# Fetter & Walecka's derivation of second quantised canonical Schrodinger equation for fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, second-quantization

On page 18, before the occupation number variables for states i and j are changed $n_i \rightarrow n'_i = n_i - 1$ and $n_j \rightarrow n'_j = n_j + 1$ respectively, could we not have rewritten eq. 1.58 as $$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi(t)\rangle \\= \dots + \sum_{n_1 n_2 \dots n_\infty} \sum_{i<j} \langle i|T|j\rangle f(n_1,\dots,n_i-1,\dots,n_j+1,\dots,t)\delta_{n_j0}\delta_{n_i1}(-1)^{Q_{ij}}\cdot\\|\dots, n_i,\dots,n_j,\dots\rangle+\dots$$, where
$$\begin{align}Q_{ij} & = \sum_{k} n_k; E_k \in (E_i, E_j)\\ & = S_j - S_i - n_i\end{align}$$,
which, after the variable change, would give
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} |\Psi(t)\rangle \\= \dots + \sum_{n'_1 n'_2 \dots n'_\infty} \sum_{i<j} \langle i|T|j\rangle f(n'_1,\dots,n'_i,\dots,n'_j,\dots,t)\delta_{n'_j1}\delta_{n'_i0}(-1)^{Q_{ij}}\cdot\\|\dots, n'_i+1,\dots,n'_j-1,\dots\rangle+\dots$$.In the text, $Q_{ij}$ is written as $n'_{i+1}+n'_{i+2}+\dots+n'_{j-1}$ which is equal to the expression I have above as the change of variables only affects. However it then says that the factor is equivalent to $S_j - S_i - n'_i  = S_j - S_i - n_i + 1$, which differs from the factor as I have it above. Can somebody explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Sorry it took longer than expected, long day. Notice that your factor $Q_{ij}$ actually appears in combination /w a delta factor that sets $n'_i =0$. So if you are ok /w $Q_{ij} = n'_{i+1} + n'_{i+2} + …+n'_{j-1}$, then $(-1)^{Q_{ij}}\delta_{n'_i 0}\delta_{n'_j 1} = (-1)^{S_j -S_i -n'_i}\delta_{n'_i 0}\delta_{n'_j 1} = (-1)^{S_j -S_i}\delta_{n'_i 0}\delta_{n'_j 1}$.

Comment: No worries, but doesn't $Q_{ij} = S_j - S_i - n_i$ which, with $\delta_{n'_{i}0} = \delta_{n_{i}1}$, would give you $Q_{ij} = S_j - S_i - 1$?

Comment: Yes, $Q_{ij} = S_j -S_i -n_i$, but $S_j -S_i -n_i = S'_j - S'_i - n'_i$ and they should have written $(-1)^{S'_j - S'_i - n'_i}$ to boot. This is because for $n'_i = n_i -1$ and $i<j$, we have $S'_i = S_i$, but $S'_j = n'_1 + n'_2 + …+ n'_{i-1} + n'_i + n'_{i+1} +…+ n'_{j-1} = n_1 + n_2 + …+ n_{i-1} + (n_i - 1) + n_{i+1} +…+ n_{j-1} = S_j - 1$.  The factor $(-1)^{S'_j - S'_i - n'_i}\delta_{n'_i 0}$ is just what is needed to recover $a_i^\dagger a_j |n'_1n'_2…n'_{\infty}\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you want to add that solution as an answer to the question so you get the reputation for it?

Comment: Nah.. But welcome.

Comment: @udrv Hi again. I'm very grateful but I'm afraid I have another [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/234816/fetter-waleckas-derivation-of-second-quantised-potential-term-in-many-particl). Do you mind having a look if you have the time?